# JQUERY - Trim Function Not Working

Tags: jquery, input, trim

The trim function does not work correctly

```
<input class="input"></input>
<div class="button">CLICK</div>



$(".button").click(function() {

    var name = $( ".input" ).val(); 

    name = $.trim(name);

    console.log("TRIM " + name);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5sufd9jj/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trim removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

If you want to remove *consecutive* spaces such as `'string         string'`, use the following:

```
$.trim(name.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LL9kxhf/)

```js
$(".button").on('click', function() {
    var name = $.trim($('input').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
    console.log("TRIM " + name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input"></input>
<div class="button">CLICK</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is working all right.

trim function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string.

It DOES NOT remove spaces from the middle.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have any value of your input element therefore an empty string returned

http://jsfiddle.net/lakshay/5sufd9jj/1/

```
$(".button").click(function() {

var name = $( ".input" ).val(); 

name = $.trim(name);

$(".input").attr("value",name);\\To show the trimmed sring
```

});

Answer (score 0):

String.prototype.trim()

```
const greeting = '   Hello world!   ';
console.log(greeting); // expected output: "   Hello world!   ";
console.log(greeting.trim()); // expected output: "Hello world!";
```

Polyfill:

Running the following code before any other code will create trim() if it's not natively available.

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
```